# Selected row/rows have a hover state

Tags: javascript, html, select, checkbox, hover

I have done a table in `<div id="middle" class="fl">` 
It looks like this:!
In Fiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/qqmhao/e2N4e/1/

Now I have to do these:

- Rows have a hover state
- Rows can be selected without the checkbox
- Multiple rows may be selected

Any help thanks very much in advanced!!

Comment: Where's your JavaScript?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: You mean for progressbar? It's from jQuery UI @Zenith

Comment: ''Rows can be selected without checkbox'' - you should activate checkbox on row click, it will be easier with jquery.

Comment: @Sunny Yes! You need to show what you have tried so far and give us a jsFiddle also please :)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/qqmhao/e2N4e/1/ @Zenith Here it is~ :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

this code may be help you => on tr click if check box is checked that uncheck it else check it

for tr hover effect you can write css

http://jsfiddle.net/e2N4e/6/

```
    $('table tr').click(function(){
  if(!$(event.target).is(":checkbox"))
  {

        if($(this).find('[type="checkbox"]').is(':checked')){
            $(this).find('[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked',false)
            $(this).removeAttr('style');
        }
       else{
         $(this).find('[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked',true)

         $(this).css('background', 'yellow');
    }
}
    })

<style>
table tr:hover{
    background:yellow;

}
</style>
```

Comment: But the checkbox doesn't work now, right? And for hover I used `tr:hover { background: #FCF; }` in css.. Whereas all I want is that rows can be selected but not checkbox, hover states show up when select the rows... Here is the new one:http://jsfiddle.net/qqmhao/e2N4e/4/ @sangram parmar

Answer (score 1):

Clickable rows:

```
$('table').on('click', 'tr', function() {
    var $row = $(this);
    var $checkbox = $row.find('[type=checkbox]');
    $checkbox.click();
});
```

Hoverable rows:

```
tr:hover {
    background-color: grey;
}
```

Enabled state:

```
$('table').on('click', '[type=checkbox]', function(e) {
    var $checkbox = $(this);
    var $row = $checkbox.parents('tr');
    e.stopPropagation(); // Prevents the other click handler from being called
    if($checkbox.prop('checked')) {
        $row.addClass('checked');
    } else {
        $row.removeClass('checked');
    }
});
```

Enabled state CSS:

```
tr.checked {
    background-color: cyan;
}
```

Obviously, this would need some more work - for example highlighting rows whose checkboxes were enabled in HTML. But you get the gist.

Comment: Yh.Thank you all the same.:) That's the second method..As cool as the first one ..But it's a bit harder to understand.. @Rudolph Gottesheim

Comment: @Sunny I would argue it's the nicer code, sice I'm not actually setting CSS properties via JavaScript. But you're definately right in that the other answer is easier to read and understand, and you can more or less just drop it in. :)

Comment: Really? So we should avoid setting CSS properties via JavaScript? Hmmm.. @Rudolph Gottesheim

Comment: @Sunny By setting and removing class names via JS and applying the style itself you're separating concerns. JavaScript (or the DOM for that matter) itself shouldn't have anything to do with with the appearance of the page. Class names are the bridge for that. You shouldn't have to go to your JavaScript code to change how an active row *looks*. CSS is made for that. Doug Neiner talked about this at the last jQuery conference in Vienna. He also wrote [a blog post](http://code.dougneiner.com/coding/using-css-classes-for-states.html) about it.